# Why babel is compiling normal functions to arrow functions when webpack is in production mode?

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs, babel-loader

I'm new to webpack and Babel and I'm getting quite crazy even following the docs. For example, on Babel docs the say I should use babel.config.json

https://babeljs.io/docs/en/configuration

But then they title .babelrc, still speaking of babel.config.json

https://babeljs.io/setup#installation

But then I find an article when a guy uses babel.config.js (not json, and with commonjs syntax)

https://www.andrewsouthpaw.com/basic-babel-webpack-setup-in-2020/

But, ok, anyway, this is my test code:

webpack config:

```
module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: './dist/js/main.js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.m?js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
          }
        }
      } // babel
    ] // rules
  } // module
};
```

babel.config.json

```
{
  'presets': ['@babel/env']
}
```

index.js

```
//import _ from 'lodash';

const text = 'test';

function test(){
  _.delay(function(){
    console.log(text) }
  , 200);

  return 'done';
}

let a_string = test();

document.write(a_string);
```

...And... This is the compiled file content:

```
(()=>{var e=(_.delay((function(){console.log("test")}),200),"done");document.write(e)})();
```

Why does babel insert an arrow function? Shouldn't it be the exact opposite?

Comment: Minification of the module iife, I presume? Also notice how it inlines `test`.

Comment: Why is this an issue?

Comment: Babel defaults to generating output that's supported by ES5 browsers (i.e. IE11), and the `=>` syntax was only added in ES6. You'll need to use a different `preset` or configuration to force ES6 output: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env

Comment: That `(()=>{})()` could be generated by webpack. Try to set `target: ['web', 'es5']` in `webpack.config.js` if you're using webpack 5.

Comment: @chenxsan I think that worked, output now is `!function(){var n=(_.delay((function(){console.log("test")}),200),"done");document.write(n)}();`

Comment: Still, I feel that 'test' string in console a little strange, can't really understand why it didn't keep the original variable.

Comment: Well both `text` and `test` are locally defined and only used once, so they get inlined.

Comment: @Bergi: ah I didn't know, is it a babel or webpack automation?

Comment: I'd guess it's a minifier automatically enabled by webpack in production builds. Not certain.

Comment: """Why is this an issue?"""

Because in React + TS setup arrow functions aren't always introspectable.